# how to manipulate 2d list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to replace elements in a 2d list. e-g I have this list

```
[['0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0'], 
 ['0', '0', '0']]
```

and I want to convert first row to 1,1,1

here is what I have tried

```
l = [["0"]*3]*3

for i in range(3):
  l[0][i] = "1"
```

but I am getting the following output instead

```
[['1', '1', '1'],
 ['1', '1', '1'], 
 ['1', '1', '1']]
```

why is it converting all the rows to 1s?

I also tried to insert one element like this

```
l[1][1] = 1
```

and this coverts the [1] element of every row to 1 like this

```
[['0', 1, '0'], 
 ['0', 1, '0'], 
 ['0', 1, '0']]
```

Am I making a silly mistake or my interpreter has issues?

Comment: It's not a silly mistake so much as a _common_ one, and no, nothing is wrong with your interpreter.

Comment: Just to add to the answers below: You can use the `id` function to get a number that identifies an object. Applying that to your matrix, you could observe that it contains three references to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the multiplication, the inner lists are all the same object. This is basically the same as:

```py
inner = ["0"] * 3
outer = [inner, inner, inner]
```

When you now change `inner`, (or one element of `outer`), you change all references of it.

If you want to generate a 2D list with independent elements, i suggest list comprehension:

```py
[["0" for i in range(3)] for j in range (3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interpreter is not the issue. I think you are just constructing your matrix incorrectly. You can just change the first row of the matrix as such

```
matrix = [['0'] * 3 for _ in range(3)


for i in range(3):
    matrix[0][i] = '1'
```

Comment: how is that any different from my code?

Comment: i made the matrix differently. try it like that

Comment: On each iteration of the list comprehension, a _new_ list is created.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
l = [ [0]*3 for i in range(3)]
```

In your code they all point to the same object.